# Using a field to filter a selection on a second field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `ClientContacts`, which holds basic information about a pairing of clients. Some of the details held in this table include `P1Title`, `P2Title`, `P1FirstName`, `P2FirstName`. For each row in this table there may be details of one or two clients, with a `CustomerId` that represents the pairing. Within this table is also `ContactId`, which is used to link to the table described below.

In a second table `ContactDetails` which contains rows that hold a specific contact detail that is associated with a client. Each client may have a number of rows in this table, each row holding a different detail such as `HomeNumber`, `MobileNumber` and `Email`. This table also contains a `Type` field which represents the type of contact detail held in the row. 1 = Home number, 2 = Mobile number and 3 = email. The `Note` field is also included, which may hold either `Mr` or `Mrs` denoting whether the mobile number held belongs to Person1 or Person2 in the client pairing.

Here is a visual structure of the tables.

```
ClientContacts

    CustomerId       ContactId        Person1Title           Person1FirstName       Person1LastName        Person2Title          Person2FirstName       Person2LastName     
    1                100              Mr                     Bob                    BobLastname            Mrs                   Bobette                BobetteLastname      
    2                101              Mr                     John                   JohnLastname           Mrs                   Johnette               JohnetteLastname
```

ContactDetails

```
    ContactId          Detail           Type      Note
    100                012345           1         
    100                077777           2         P1
    100                012333           1
    100                088888           2         P2
    101                099999           1
    101                012211           1
    101                066666           2
    101                email@email.com  3
```

I want to construct a query that allows me to pull back the information of both of the clients, as well as figure out whether any of the mobile numbers stored in the `ContactDetails` table belongs to either of the two clients, if it does, I need to be able to tell which belongs to Person1 or Person2 in the pairing.

In addition, if the note field is null for a particular mobile number (type = 2), the first mobile number should be used for Person1 and the second should be used for Person2.

Below is my desired output:

```
Output

CustomerId      Person1Firstname    

Person1Lastname          Person2Firstname        Person2Lastname          Home        Person1Mobile       Person2Mobile        Person2Email
1               Bob                     BobLastname              Bobette                 BobetteLastname          012211      077777              088888               null
```

I have a partially working query that manages to extract the mobile numbers and relates them to P1 or P2, however this only works if the `Note` field is not null.

```
select 
    cc.CustomerId,
    cc.Person1Forename,
    cc.Person1Surname,
    cc.Person2Forename,
    cc.Person2Surname,
    max(case when cd.Type = 3 then cd.Detail end) as 'Home',
    max(case when cd.Type = 4 and cd.Note = cc.P1Title then cd.Detail end) as 'Person1Mobile',
    max(case when cd.Type = 4 and cd.Note = cc.P2Title then cd.Detail end) as 'Person2Mobile',
    max(case when cd.Type = 5 then cd.Detail end) as 'Email'        
from ClientContacts cc join
     ContactDetails
     cd on cc.ContactId = cd.ContactId
```

I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so what should happen if note is null?  test for it with logic, using ...cd.note is NULL....

Comment: If note is null then the first mobile number found should be placed into `P1Mobile`, the second mobile number into `P2Mobile`. I'm not sure how to write this in sql